# dependently typed morphisms in a category?

Tags: category-theory, type-theory

A morphism in a category has a domain and codomain: $f:A\to B$

In dependent type theory, we can have functions with a "dependent type", meaning that the codomain depends on the input. This can be written as: $f:(a:A)\to B_a$, where $B_a$ is a type (or set ...) that is parameterized by elements of $A$.

Can we formalize such "dependently typed morphisms" in the context of category theory? Is this a done?

Comment: nLab has this: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/categorical+model+of+dependent+types